# Scheduler that can ignore the minutes

Tags: python, scheduler, apscheduler

How can I run a job at certain period of time (for example between 9-12am), once every hour, regardless the minutes? Sometimes the platform I used to run the job started at 9:02, therefore often it missed the job at 9 o'clock.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a counter to counter how many time it runs per day. And for every ten minutes for example, you check whether the counter is with correct value. Let's says the server starts at 9:02, and 9:10 the script checked the counter which should be 1 but 0. in this case, you just run that job. I think this could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about apscheduler (based on the tags), you can just set a more generous misfire grace time of 1 hour.

Comment: Hi @Alex Grönholm, yes my preference is using apscheduler. What's the difference between misfire_grace_time and jitter? And I seem can't cancel the job although I use this:

`scheduler.add_job(main,'cron', hour=hours, misfire_grace_time=60, coalesce=True)`
    `try:`
        `while True:
            `time.sleep(1)`
    `except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):`
        `scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)`

Comment: Jitter adds a randomized delay to the job. Misfire grace time defines the maximum delay for the start of the job before it's considered a misfire and not run.

Comment: If the job has already started executing, it cannot be cancelled.

Comment: I tested this scenario: 'scheduler.add_job(main,'cron', hour='9-10', misfire_grace_time=3600, coalesce=True)' and run it at 09:05, and it didn't execute the code until the next hour DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2021-06-20 10:00:00+00:00. I'd like to use apscheduler, is there a way for me to run the 09:00 o'clock job if the system went down and came back up say ten past 9? Thanks heaps!